# import not found error for sbt.build file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, scalariform

I am in the learning process for Scala and sbt.  I have an existing project I am starting with.

On the command line under top project folder, as soon as I enter the sbt command I get:

```
C:\Projects\aproject\build.sbt:1: error: not found: object scalariform

import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

C:\Projects\aProject\build.sbt:2: error: object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform
```

I can't find an online reference for this specific error.  I assume the second error is because of the first error.

The `sbt.build` file has these three imports:

```
import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform.ScalariformKeys
```

I have scala version 2.13.0
and sbt version 1.2.8

Answer (score 2):

Add to `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.8.3")
```

and refresh the project.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform

Comment: Didn't help,  Same issue.

Comment: Ignore above comment.  Same issue, different dependency.   It now has problems with org.scalastyle:scalastyle-sbt-plugin:0.8.0.  I will investigate.  Thanks.